# The 'now' option in fullcalendar v1.6.4 is no longer working

Tags: fullcalendar

I used fetch the server time, and set as fullcalendar 'today' time using the 'now' option. It used to work for me but recently it stopped working.

Documentation : http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/timezone/now/

I have tested on jsfiddle, where it fails to work as well, and just picks up the browser's time. Link : http://jsfiddle.net/siddharthac/Ak877/43/

Sample code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        now: "2012-04-08T00:00:00",
        editable: true
    });

});
```

Comment: now is only available for v2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'now' is only available for v2. I don't think this is available at all in 1.6.* version.